# How to include $ character on a pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to include a price through a pseudo element

```css
h3:after{
    content: " (+ $75)";
}
```

```html
<h3>price</h3>
```

But using CSS minifier prevents the "$75" to appear.
Is there a way to escape the compiler?

Comment: Have you tried the entity value instead `\0024`?

Comment: Why do you put price data into pseudo element?

Comment: This is for a mockup, it is not supposed to be final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the entity number. Although I must caution you, this looks like the beginnings of badly designed road that will lead to horrible code practices.

```css
h3:after{
    content: " (+ \0024 75)";
}
```

```html
<h3>price</h3>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use it as a data-attribute:

```css
h3:after{
    content: " (+ " attr(data-symbole)"75)";
}
```

```html
<h3 data-symbole="$">price</h3>
```

Or use all the text as a data-attribute:

```css
h3:after{
    content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<h3 data-content=" (+ $75)">price</h3>
```